Identification for L313 marking, 5 pins
Anyone have any idea what these two chips are? I believe they could be voltage regulators, but I am not too sure as I can't find the documentation anywhere. Both of them are connected to multiple connectors, and then some other components and transistors. They are located on a display board, but don't think they are directly connected to the seven segment displays.



With more of the board visible you should be able to reverse-engineer what they are. For example if the first is an adjustable linear regulator there would be a voltage divider and a feedback trace.

VAL1
Based upon codes starting with VA this could be the obsolete S-1135C20-M5T1S LDO Voltage Regulators LINEAR LDO REG HI 60UA IQ 300MA IOUT. From the datasheet found linked on the Mouser website it is a SOT-23-5 package:

The first 3 characters on the marking are VAL which the datasheet shows is for S-1135C20-M5T1y.  For the orderable part number:

C is the Product Type which is described in the datasheet.
20 means an output voltage of 2.0 V ±1.0%.
The final y is the Environmental code:

U: Lead-free (Sn 100%), halogen-free
S: Lead-free, halogen-free



The 4th character of the marking is the Lot number, and therefore not relevant to identifying the device.
L313
codes starting with 'L3' has several devices starting with a marking code of L31, but at the moment not sure of the manufacturer as can't see any logo in the picture of the device.

The L3 SOT23-5 device could be a MaxLinear SPX3819. I saw on a few websites with this product and they all start with L3 and have that vertical line before the "L".

I actually don't think it's the SOT -23-5 anymore, because I checked the connections and seems like pin 5 is gnd and pin 2 is Vcc which doesn't match the datasheet

I think its a TI TLV2731 as it matches the pin connections and part marking.
